# File class and array in java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, java-io

I am stuck when writing a Java program. I have to calculate the grade of 121 students and store them in an array for later use. But the array I created does not have the values from the for loop.

```
public class GradeCalculator{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        File grade = fileName();
        int lines = getNumEntries(grade);
        print(grade, lines);
    }
    public static File fileName(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the grade file");
        String fileName = scan.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        while(!file.exists()){
            System.out.println("your input file does not exist");
            fileName = scan.nextLine();
            file = new File(fileName);
        }return file;       
    }

    public static int getNumEntries(File fln){
        File file = fln;
        int count = 0;
        try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner (fln);
            while(input.hasNextLine()){
                count++;
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }return count;  
    }

    public static void print(File fln, int values)throws NoSuchElementException{
        File file = fln;
        int []a = new int [values];
        try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            for(int i=0; i<=a.length; i++){
                while(input.hasNextDouble()){
                    double Lab = input.nextDouble();
                    double A1 = input.nextDouble()/10*4;
                    double A2 = input.nextDouble()/10*4;
                    double A3 = input.nextDouble()/10*4;
                    double A4 = input.nextDouble()/10*4;
                    double A5 = input.nextDouble()/10*4;
                    double A6 = input.nextDouble()/10*4;
                    double A7 = input.nextDouble()/10*4;
                    double Midterm1 = input.nextDouble()/20*15;
                    double Midterm2 = input.nextDouble()/35*15;
                    double Final = input.nextDouble()/110*37;
                    a[i]= (int)(Lab+A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6+A7+Midterm1+Midterm2+Final);
                    System.out.println(a[i]); //If I put the println here the values are correct
                }
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }System.out.println(a[i]); //If I put the println here the values are different
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You consume all of your input in the inner while loop on the first iteration of the outer for loop. Also, you are repeatedly setting `a[0]` to the grade instead of each and every index possible within the array. Then your for loop finishes and you have an array like:

```
{lastGrade, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0}
```

Basically, you need to get rid of the while loop. There may be other problems as well.

Comment: If I get rid of the while loop, its showed ''Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)at GradeCalculator.print(GradeCalculator.java:47)at GradeCalculator.main(GradeCalculator.java:10)" I have to repeat the process 121 times, I was wondering what should I add if I want the values to store in the array